# Oracle SQL - Add numbers separated by delimiter, columnwise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple rows with values like

```
a_b_c_d_e_f and x_y_z_m_n_o
```

and I need a SQL query with a result like `a+x_b+y_c+z_d+m.......`

Sample data as requested
[image: Sample Data]

What I am willing to do is aggregate it at Datetime..aggregating Total is simple, but how can I do that for the last column, thanks.

Expected Result
[image]

Comment: Please show actual sample data in _tabular_ form.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Updated question mate, thanks.

Comment: The best solution would be to fix your data model and don't store delimited values in a single column.

Comment: Your sample data and description don't match.  But the best advice is to fix the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; read comments within code. I didn't feel like typing too much so two dates will have to do.

Sample data (you already have that & don't type it. Code you need begins at line #10):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  test (datum, total, col) as
  4    (select date '2020-07-20', 100, '10,0,20,30,0' from dual union all
  5     select date '2020-07-20', 150, '15,3,40,30,2' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select date '2020-07-19', 200, '50,6,50,30,8' from dual union all
  8     select date '2020-07-19', 300, '20,1,40,10,2' from dual
  9    ),
```

Split CSV values into rows. Note the `RB` value which will help us sum matching values

```
 10  -- split comma-separated values into rows
 11  temp as
 12    (select
 13        datum,
 14        total,
 15        to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, column_value)) val,
 16        column_value rb
 17      from test cross join
 18        table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 19                            connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
 20                           ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 21    ),
```

Computing summaries is simple; nothing special about it. We'll keep the `RB` value as it'll be needed in the last step:

```
 22  -- compute summaries
 23  summary as
 24    (select datum,
 25       sum(total) total,
 26       sum(val) sumval,
 27       rb
 28     from temp
 29     group by datum, rb
 30    )
```

The last step. Using `LISTAGG`, aggregate comma-separated values back, but this time added to each other:

```
 31  -- final result
 32  select datum,
 33    total,
 34    listagg(sumval, ',') within group (order by rb) new_col
 35  from summary
 36  group by datum, total
 37  order by datum desc, total;

DATUM                    TOTAL NEW_COL
------------------- ---------- --------------------
20.07.2020 00:00:00        250 25,3,60,60,2
19.07.2020 00:00:00        500 70,7,90,40,10

SQL>
```